# Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed" (1004): Save xls file as xlsx, close and then reopen it

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I'm running into an issue with a macro that I created giving a "method saveas of object _workbook failed" error periodically. It can work 60 times in a row and then error out on the 61st time.

In order for the macro to handle the number of rows in the sheet I need to convert the file the code is being ran in from .xls format to .xlsx. The beginning of my code saves the file as a .xlsx file and then continue on with the macro as planned.

Is there something in my code that is causing this error to generate from time to time? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the beginning of the code where the error is occurring.

```
'Save and Rename file, Change from xls. to xlsx, Close File, Reopen File.
Dim myactiveworkbook As Workbook
Dim myactiveworkbookname As String
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    myactiveworkbookname = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    myactiveworkbookname = Replace(myactiveworkbookname, "xls", "xlsx")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="Customer Balance Details", _
         FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="Customer Balance Details"
    
Set myactiveworkbook = ActiveWorkbook

 myactiveworkbookname = myactiveworkbook.Name

myactiveworkbook.Close

Workbooks.Open (myactiveworkbookname)

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

I've tried a few suggestions I've found on other posts but I cannot get the code to work after I implement the changes. Thisworkbook as an example. I am not sure if I am entering the code correctly though as this is new to me.

Comment: Btw you don't need to `Workbooks.Open` the file you already have open, then close it, then open it again.

Comment: Can an xlsx file have VBA code?  As I know only xlsm files can have VBA code

Answer (score 0):

> ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="**Customer Balance Details**", _
> FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False Workbooks.Open Filename:="**Customer Balance Details**"

1. **Filename** should conclude file extension like .xlsm/xlsx/xls
2. Is the vba code saved in .xls file? 
   If the answer is yes, since .xlsx can't keep vba codes,

- if you wish to keep codes in the new file: 
  `new_name="Customer Balance Details"&".xlsm" 

  new_path=thisworkbook.path & "\" & new_name
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=new_path, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

  Workbooks.Open Filename:=new_path`
- if you dont need to keep codes in the new file: 
  `new_name="Customer Balance Details"&".xlsx" 

  new_path=thisworkbook.path & "\" & new_name
  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=new_path, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacrodDisabled,, CreateBackup:=False 

  Workbooks.Open Filename:=new_path`